# Intercepting process.stdout.write calls

Tags: javascript, logging, io, node.js

Hey, seems like this should be simple enough, but I must be missing something. I tried using pipe and on('data') but neither seem to pass me data. The reason I want to do this is I want to be able to have a "dev" section and have the output be streamed to that, but I'd rather not have to write to a file then read from a file then stream that if I can just intercept the data on the write call.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would just be to just replace *process.stdout.write* with your function. Something like:

```
process.stdout.write = function() { /* Do your stuff*/ }
```